# Is it possible in (android) xml resource android:text to have variable format float precision?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, floating-accuracy

Having a text resource like this

```
<string name="list_item_station_detail_current_price_price_text">%1$.2f</string>
```

Used in a layout xml like this

```
android:text="@{@string/list_item_station_detail_current_price_price_text(currentPrice.price)}"
```

My trouble is that the precision isn't always 2 digits ( `%1$.2f` ), it may be variable. Is there a clever trick to fix this, maybe nested strings, or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a string array where each entry represents a different precision.

```
<string-array name="list_item_station_detail_current_price_price_text">
    <item>%1$.2f</item>
    <item>%1$.3f</item>
    <item>%1$.4f</item>
</string-array>
```

In the XML, define the text for the `TextView` as follows:

```
   android:text="@{String.format(@stringArray/list_item_station_detail_current_price_price_text[currentPrice.precision],currentPrice.price)}"
```

I assume that you have or can create a variable with the precision.

Based upon the precision, the appropriate string is selected. (Precision of 2 maps to index 0, 3->1, 4->2) The price is the argument to the selected string.

Comment: Thanx for answering, will check it out. Yes, the precision can be saved in the data structure.